# Vee-Validate. Using flags on the field value returns undefined? Written with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vee-validate

https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/flags.html#introduction

According to the documentation, I should be able to get a boolean when using a flag on the value of one of the fields.
Eg.

```
computed: {
    isFormDirty() {
      return Object.keys(this.fields).some(key => this.fields[key].dirty);
    }
 },
```

I am trying to disable the submit button of my form until all fields are valid. My form is a bit long so I will keep it short. All the attributes of the inputs are structured like the following:

`type="text", @change="updateForm", name="surname", v-validate="'required'", v-model="form.surname", id="surname"`. All the inputs are wrapped by a `<form>` tag.

The updateForm method looks like:

`updateForm(event): void {
    this.$store.commit('updateForm', this.form)
  }`

where the mutation 'updateForm' looks like:

`updateForm(state, data) {
   state.form = data;
 },`

The submit button looks like:

`<button type="submit" :disabled="isFormValid">Submit</button>`

where isFormValid is a computed property that looks like:

`get isFormValid(): boolean {
    return Object.keys(this.form).some(key => this.form[key].invalid);
  }`

The form data is also a computed property:

`get form(): FormData {
    return this.$store.getters.getForm();
 }`

The problem is when I `console.log(Object.keys(this.form).map(key => this.form[key])` or `console.log(this.$validator.fields.items.map(item => item.value)` inside `isFormValid()`, I am getting the values of the fields. However, when I attach an invalid flag after them, it shows undefined instead of the boolean I am expecting. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit more research and playing around with the object being returned and figured out that the flags can only be accessed after `.flags` after `$validator.fields`.

I ended up getting an array with a boolean for all of my fields when I did 
`console.log((this.$validator.fields).map(field => field.flags.invalid))`.

my isFormValid() ended up looking like:

```
 get isFormValid(): boolean {
    const a = function(e) {
      return e === true;
    }
    return (this.$validator.fields).map(field => field.flags.invalid).some(a)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem and it was because `this.$validator.fields` were empty when the component was being rendered. If you use:

```
isFormDirty() {
  if (this.fields) {
    return Object.keys(this.fields).some(key => this.fields[key].dirty);
  }
  return;
}
```

It will work fine!